# How can I run IPython after I installed it via pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

I installed `IPython` via

`python3 -m pip install ipython[all]`

And now I am wondering how to set an `alias` or `symlink` to run it from the console via

`ipython3`

Hope you can help me here! Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you installed it to a cusotom location. You can setup an alias in your `~/.bashrc` like `alias ipython3='/path/to/ipython3'`

Comment: Yes, it would be in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython` for example, but I am not sure which file I'd need to launch it!?

Comment: go to that directory, do a `ls -la`. Look out for executable files in that output (their file permission will be something like `-rw..-rw-x`, i.e., terminating with `-x`).

Comment: If you are still not able to figure out, paste the directory structure in pastebin so that there is more relevant information.

Comment: I did, but there are so many of those... this was why I was asking which of them could be the one that launches IPython in the terminal

Comment: This would be an ls -la on the top dir if it helps: http://pastebin.com/5czuTnFz

Comment: Okay, got it, its in IPython/terminal/ipapp.py

Answer (score 0):

Okay, nevermind, found it under

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/I‌​Python/terminal/ipapp.py`

I someone is interested, I just put together some walkthrough for installing IPython in a custom dir... [Here is the link](https://github.com/rasbt/tutorials_cheatsheets/blob/master/Python/inst_sci_python_packages.md#ipython)